# How do I remove the last character from a string in a textBox?

Tags: string, visual-c++

I am trying to create a calculator program similar to what Windows has, and I am currently having trouble with making a backspace key. It should, when clicked, remove the last character from the textBox Text field.
Here what I was thinking would work:

```
private: System::Void button14_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
textBox1->Text[textBox1->TextLength] = "";  }
```

The error list looks like this:
[image: The error list]

I have also seen suggestions to use pop_back(), remove() and erase() on the Internet, but I don't have an idea how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable... you can't technically change the string.

IDK how to write this in the weird CLI C++ syntax, but something close to:

```
String^ s = textBox1->Text;
s = s^.Substring(0, s.Length - 1); // original s preserved, but no longer used
textBox1->Text = s;
```

IDK if it would allow something like, but if it does, I'd prefer it:

```
auto s = textBox1->Text;
s = s^.Substring(0, s.Length - 1); // original s preserved, but no longer used
textBox1->Text = s;
```

Comment: Hello, I have seen this method of implementation quite a lot but I didn't try it because I had no idea what that ^ symbol after the string did. What does it do exactly and how string is different from string^?

Comment: Well, the weird little ^ dereference is something for .NET/CLI in C++. Some kind of weird extension. I'm not even sure I got it right to be honest. If I need .NET, I write C#. If I need C++, I write regular C++. The important thing is that you need to follow these steps. 1) Get the text from the text box, 2) Create a modified string (chop off last character) 3) Set the text property in the textbox with the new string.  The method you were doing it wouldn't work